# ion slide box not working in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a view that looks like this:

```html
<ion-view title="Slides" ng-controller='IntroCtrl'>
  <ion-content ng-controller='IntroCtrl'>
    <h3> Slides here </h3>
    <!-- <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                      ng-click="previous()" ng-if="data.slideIndex > 0">
                Previous Slide
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right"> 
              <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                      ng-click="next()" ng-if="data.slideIndex < data.numViewableSlides - 1">
                Next
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>-->
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)">

      <ion-slide ng-repeat="slide in data.slides">
        <div ng-include src="slide.template"></div>
      </ion-slide>


    </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller

```js
.controller('IntroCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
  });
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
  });
  $scope.data = {
    numViewableSlides: 0,
    slideIndex: 0,

    slides: [{
        'template': 'templates/mylongform.html'
      },

      {
        'template': 'templates/facts.html'
      },

      {
        'template': 'templates/facts2.html'

      }
    ]
  };

  var countSlides = function() {
    $scope.data.numViewableSlides = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.slides.length; i++) {
      $scope.data.numViewableSlides++;
    }

    console.log($scope.data.numViewableSlides + " viewable slides");

  }

  countSlides();


  $scope.next = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    console.log("called next")
  };
  $scope.previous = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    console.log("called previous")
  };



  // Called each time the slide changes
  $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {

    $scope.data.slideIndex = index;
  };

})
```

I have used slideMenu Delegate because without it, the side menu swiped every time I tried to slide.

But even now, the slider does not work.
What looks wrong here?

Comment: Please format your code for better readability :) check how to markdown on SO here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: what are your trying to achieve here.. Do you want to be able to inject views in your slider?

Comment: That's right. I followed this codepen http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Kcxaw except for the dynamic part. i just need to get my predefined html views in the slides.

Comment: Fixed. Needed to take off <ion-veiw> from those html files.

Comment: Hmm I would like to see one of the template html files, plz add them in edit or post as an answer.. also this might interest you https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox , I'm currently working on something similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85506/discussion-between-pavitar-and-simran-kaur).